# KDE+SDDM won't launch Xorg can't find screen (EE)

Tags: kde, gentoo, desktop-environment, sddm

So currently I am running gentoo in CLI, and wanted to install desktop enviroment. I followed [gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SDDM), but sddm seems not to work correctly:

```
GENTOO MACHINE ~ # rc-service display-manager start --verbose
 * Executing: /lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh /lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh /etc/init.d/display-manager start
 * Setting up sddm ...
 * start-stop-daemon: fopen `/run/sddm.pid': No such file or directory
 * Detaching to start `/usr/bin/sddm' ...         [ ok ]
GENTOO MACHINE ~ #
```

I checked my /etc/conf.d/display-manager:

```
GENTOO MACHINE ~ # cat /etc/conf.d/display-manager
# We always try and start the DM on a static VT. The various DMs normally
# default to using VT7. If you wish to use the display-manager init
# script, then you should ensure that the VT checked is the same VT your
# DM wants to use.
# We do this check to ensure that you haven't accidentally configured
# something to run on the VT in your /etc/inittab file so that
# you don't get a dead keyboard.                        
CHECKVT=7                                                                                                       # What display manager do you use ?
#     [ xdm | greetd | gdm | sddm | gpe | lightdm | entrance ]
# NOTE: If this is set in /etc/rc.conf, that setting will override this one.
DISPLAYMANAGER="sddm"
```

I tried using `startx` command, but then it cannot see screen. Here's Xorg config:

```
 GENTOO MACHINE / # Xorg -configure                                                                   X.Org X Server 1.20.14                              
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0                       
Build Operating System: Linux 5.15.11-gentoo x86_64 Gentoo                                                      Current Operating System: Linux GENTOO MACHINE 5.15.11-gentoo #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 29 12:47:38 CET 2021 x86_64Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.11-gentoo root=UUID=a9ec68ee-f208-4c5f-9c9d-ed8a881c1663 ro single
Build Date: 30 December 2021  06:34:51AM                                                                        Current version of pixman: 0.40.0                               Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org                                                              to make sure that you have the latest version.  Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,                                                      (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,                                                        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.                                           (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Dec 30 06:58:53 2021                                            List of video drivers:                                          amdgpu                                                  modesetting                                     (++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"           (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"                                                 (II) AMDGPU(0): [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.       (II) AMDGPU(1): [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.                                                                                                                       Xorg is not able to detect your mouse.                  Edit the file and correct the Device.                                                                           Xorg has configured a multihead system, please check your config.                                                                                                       Your xorg.conf file is /root/xorg.conf.new                                                                      To test the server, run 'X -config /root/xorg.conf.new'                                                         (EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
    GENTOO MACHINE / #
```

Okey, so I was asked about .log file, here it is:

```
[   160.130] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.14
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   160.131] Build Operating System: Linux 5.15.11-gentoo x86_64 Gentoo
[   160.131] Current Operating System: Linux GENTOO MACHINE 5.15.11-gentoo #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 29 12:47:38 CET 2021 x86_64
[   160.131] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.11-gentoo root=UUID=a9ec68ee-f208-4c5f-9c9d-ed8a881c1663 ro
[   160.131] Build Date: 30 December 2021  06:34:51AM
[   160.131]  
[   160.131] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[   160.131]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   160.131] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   160.131] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Dec 30 08:24:07 2021
[   160.131] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   160.131] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   160.131] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   160.131] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   160.131] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   160.131] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   160.131] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   160.131] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   160.131] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   160.131] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   160.131] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/TTF/" does not exist.
[   160.131]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   160.131] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF/" does not exist.
[   160.131]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   160.131] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1/" does not exist.
[   160.131]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   160.131] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/".
[   160.131]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   160.131]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/").
[   160.131] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/misc/,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi/
[   160.131] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
[   160.131] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   160.131] (II) Loader magic: 0x556ffebd5d00
[   160.131] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   160.131]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   160.131]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[   160.131]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   160.131]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   160.132] (--) using VT number 7

[   160.132] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[   160.134] (--) PCI:*(38@0:0:0) 1002:67df:1da2:e387 rev 239, Mem @ 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/2097152, 0xfce00000/262144, I/O @ 0x0000e000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   160.134] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   160.134] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   160.136] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.136]    compiled for 1.20.14, module version = 1.0.0
[   160.136]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   160.136] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 0
[   160.136] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[   160.136] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[   160.136] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[   160.136] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   160.136] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[   160.136] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module ati
[   160.136] (EE) Failed to load module "ati" (module does not exist, 0)
[   160.136] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   160.137] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   160.137] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   160.137]    compiled for 1.20.14, module version = 1.20.14
[   160.137]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   160.137]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[   160.137] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   160.137] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[   160.137] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[   160.137] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   160.137] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[   160.137] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[   160.137] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   160.137] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   160.137] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   160.137] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   160.137] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   160.137] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   160.137] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[   160.137] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   160.137] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   160.137] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   160.137] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   160.137] (EE) 
[   160.137] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

More info about /etc/X11:

```
GENTOO MACHINE ~ # cd /etc/X11                          
GENTOO MACHINE /etc/X11 # ls                            
chooser.sh  Sessions  startDM.sh  xdm  xinit  xsm       
GENTOO MACHINE /etc/X11 #
```

Comment: Please add the contents of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` as well as relevant output of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. If it is very long, maybe just include the (EE) lines.

Comment: @Natolio I edited the answer to contain .log file, and I also need to mention that /etc/X11/ directory exists in my case, but /etc/X11/xorg.conf file doesn't.

Comment: Are there any files under `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`? Have you installed any graphics drivers? The log indicates that Xorg is trying to load several different modules, but it is failing on them.

Comment: My GPU is rx570 (which uses amdgpu drivers), I did my custom kernel setup along wiki https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/AMDGPU. About drivers themselfes - I installed it when in chroot (when I was installing the system), and they are in /lib/firmware/amdgpu. I also linked kernel to them using "Include in-kernel firmware blobs in kernel binary"

Comment: Does `lspci -nnk | grep VGA` return anything? What about `lsmod | grep -i amdgpu`? If not, can you run `modprobe amdgpu`? Just want to verify that the driver is loading properly.

Comment: I already tested lspci -nnk | grep VGA before and it returned some data about my gpu. Let me a moment, I need to check other commands as well

Comment: `modprobe` is only necessary if the module is not already loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132736/discussion-between-natolio-and-dolidod-teethtard).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not responding - I already found an answer. I had completely wrong kenrel config, as I was running custom kernel config. More info can be found here - https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8686789.html#8686789